# Align div element to bottom of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to bottom align one of three divs inside a container, but I'm having some issues.

As you will see, if I try and use absolute positioning on the `bottom-aligned` div the height becomes a problem.

I can set a specific height, but the content within the `cta-item` divs could vary from very small to very large.

I'm trying to create a solution for all use cases.

I know I can use jQuery to get the height of the largest `cta-item` div and adjust accordingly, but I'm trying to avoid using jQuery/JS for this whenever possible.

I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vmpb7042/1/) with what I currently have.

Thank you in advance!

```css
.dynamic-cta-ctr {
  display: flex;
}
.dynamic-cta-ctr .cta-item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
}
.dynamic-cta-ctr .cta-item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.dynamic-cta-ctr .cta-item .bottom-aligned {
  /* position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="dynamic-cta-ctr">
  <div class="cta-item">
    <div class="heading-text"><h3>Some content</h3></div>
    <div class="cta-field-content">Some content that sort of hangs around</div>
    <div class="bottom-aligned"><h5>Bottom aligned content</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-item">
    <div class="heading-text"><h3>You can have your cake and eat it too!</h3></div>
    <div class="cta-field-content">Some content that sort of hangs around</div>
    <div class="bottom-aligned"><h5>Bottom aligned content</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cta-item">
    <div class="heading-text"><h3>More people will come if you say we have punch and pie</h3></div>
    <div class="cta-field-content">Some content that sort of hangs around</div>
    <div class="bottom-aligned"><h5>Bottom aligned content</h5></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
.cta-item {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom-aligned {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vmpb7042/4/)

More details here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: feels like 2017. outstanding solution.